# Spark plug blown out of engine in one cylinder, twice.

Tags: sparkplugs

I have a 454 engine in my cabin cruiser boat.  After operating at normal cruising speed for 20 minutes or so a spark plug was blown out of the engine, with the center electrode melted, and the rest of the plug left in place.  I replaced that plug, checked the others and they were fine.  The next time out, the same cylinder, brand new spark plug blew out again, same deal, melted electrode and the whole center of the plug blown out of the engine.  It has a mercruiser electronic ignition.  Any Ideas??

Comment: This is a new one on me. You are saying the insulator and terminal are blown out from the shell? Just the shell sitting in the head with no damage to the threads in the head? Is the engine fuel injected or carbureted? Does the engine sound well while running? Any strange noises?

Comment: If you could post a picture of the aftermath of one of the sparkplugs, it would probably help (maybe a couple of shots of it so we can see the electrode which was melted, as well as the parts which were still in the head).

Comment: I have heard of such an event when the cylinder is experiencing severe detonation.

Comment: Any chance water is getting into the exhaust manifold, due to poor risers or exhaust port flapper seals?

Comment: Could be detonation caused by water getting into the cylinder through the exhaust.

Comment: @FredWilson - If it were to get water into the cylinder, it would *prevent* detonation, not cause it. Water injection systems in effect raise the octane rating of fuel by about 10 points. Besides, considering the exhaust valve is only open during the exhaust cycle, I doubt you're going to get water into the cylinder with all of the exhaust gases trying to get out.

Comment: @vini_i - That's kind of what I was thinking. If the engine is port fuel injected and the injector for that cylinder was not allowing the proper amount of fuel, you'd have an extreme lean condition in that cylinder, which could cause severe detonation. About the only way I see what is being described as happening. This theory would be shot to crud if it's carbureted, though ;-)

Comment: @paulster You are right, water should cool combustion.  Just that I have seen engine control systems do really weird things when water enters a cylinder through the exhaust valve.

Comment: @verncarpenter   It's possible that you have a collapsed lifter on that cylinder and the heat cannot escape.  It's a reach, I know, but I have seen this before.  have you noticed and strange sounds emerging from the engine?